# Добавление разделителя в импортированный csv-файл, используя Python

Tags: python, база-данных, mongodb, csv

сразу скажу, что в Python я новичок и мне нужна ваша помощь.
У меня есть csv-файл,который я импортирую в mongodb, имеющий вид:

```
Имя,номер телефона, дополнительный номер телефона, mail, количество и название машин.
---------------------------------------------------------------
ИмяЧеловека1, НомерЧеловека1, НомерЧеловека1(2), ""1"-BMW X5"
ИмяЧеловека2, НомерЧеловека2, ЕмейлЧеловека2, ""2"-Audi A3, Mazda 6"
ИмяЧеловека3,               , ЕмейлЧеловека3,   ""1"-BMW X5"
ИмяЧеловека4, НомерЧеловека4,               ,   ""2"-Audi A3, Mazda 6"
```

Как видно на примере, сам файл кривой, из-за чего при переносе в базу данных получаю:

```
    Имя          Номер1            Номер2              Мейл       Кол.и название машин
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ИмяЧеловека1 НомерЧеловека1    ДопНомерЧеловека1   ""1"-BMW X5"           null
    ИмяЧеловека2 НомерЧеловека2    МейлЧеловека2       ""2"-Audi A3, Mazda 6" null
    ИмяЧеловека3   null            ЕмейлЧеловека3       ""1"-BMW X5"     null         

    ИмяЧеловека4 НомерЧеловека4    null                 ""2"-Audi A3, Mazda 6"    null
```

То есть, в базе данных, количество и название машин переносится в мейл, а нужно, чтобы было всё под своими столбиками(если нет доп номера - null в "Номер2", а если нет mail`а, то null, соответственно, в mail).

Вот код, который я использовал для импорта:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import pymongo
import json



def import_content(filepath):
    mng_client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    mng_db = mng_client['mongodb_name'] // Replace mongo db name
    collection_name = 'collection_name' // Replace mongo db collection name
    db_cm = mng_db[collection_name]
    cdir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    file_res = os.path.join(cdir, filepath)

    data = pd.read_csv(file_res, delimiter = ',')
    data_json = json.loads(data.to_json(orient='records'))
    db_cm.remove()
    db_cm.insert(data_json)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  filepath = '/path/to/csv/path'  // pass csv file path
  import_content(filepath)
```

То есть, по сути, мне нужен скрипт, который прочтёт построчно всё в csv файле, и если, например, увидит "@", то поставит ещё один разделитель, перед мейлом! А если не увидит, то поставит разделитель перед количеством и названием автомобиля.

Понимаю что нужно работать через модуль csv, но не знаю как. Прошу помочь! Заранее благодарю.

Comment: воспользуйтесь одной из следующих функций [df["col_name"].str.split()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [df["col_name"].str.extract()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html). Для более конкретного ответа нужны воспроизводимые данные. Лучше всего будет предоставить несколько строк из вашего CSV файла, предварительно анонимизировав персональные данные

Comment: Можете пояснить каким образом вы смогли получить после парсинга  CSV в одной ячейке значение `"2"-Audi A3, Mazda 6` - любой парсер разбил бы это на две ячейки?? [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Прошу прощения, ошибка, исправил. Для понимания сейчас пример csv сделаю более широко.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем случае с файлом ничего сделать нельзя, кроме как поправить его вручную. Вы приводите файл, в которым некоторые столбцы смещены, а другие -- нет. Например, в 3м столбце есть как e-mail'ы, так и номера телефонов. Соответственно, все столбцы, которые находятся далее, за ними также уезжают. Из приведённого примера не представляется возможным понять, как сформирован весь файл, а значит невозможно предложить решение по исправлению этого файла.

```
Имя,номер телефона, дополнительный номер телефона, mail, количество и название машин.
---------------------------------------------------------------
ИмяЧеловека1, НомерЧеловека1, НомерЧеловека1(2), ""1"-BMW X5"
ИмяЧеловека2, НомерЧеловека2, ЕмейлЧеловека2, ""2"-Audi A3, Mazda 6"
ИмяЧеловека3,               , ЕмейлЧеловека3,   ""1"-BMW X5"
ИмяЧеловека4, НомерЧеловека4,               ,   ""2"-Audi A3, Mazda 6"
```

Я также отмечу, что, возможно, Вам стоит посмотреть в сторону того, чтобы исправить способ получения этого файла, а не исправлять сам файл

Comment: Да, вы правы, получается, что количество столбцов больше чем условий. Поэтому я и пытаюсь найти функцию, которое увеличит в каждой строки разделитель на единицу. Либо же ввести регулярное выражение, которое "видя" в ячейке "@" будет добавлять ещё одну ' , '. Неужели нет такой возможности. Вручную изменять файл очень долго, больше 1000 строк.

Comment: @6crimes в каком месте нужно увеличить разделитель на 1. Конкретизируйте задача

Comment: Если есть ЕМЕЙЛ - перед е-мейл, если его нет- перед адресом. Чтобы число столбцов совпадало с данными.

Comment: Есть `e-mail` -- это `not null`?

Comment: Должно быть, что если есть Мейл, то в последнем стобце не null, а информация о машинах, а Мейл, соответственно должен идти в столбец с названием "mail" , а не в доп. телефон

Comment: @6crimes Что Вы понимаете под словом *есть*? Это строка нулевой длины, `null`? Что-то ещё? `regexp`, наконец?

Comment: Под словом "есть" я понимаю, что необходимо построчно прочитать этот csv файл, и если программа увидит 'мейл(по знаку @, допустим)' , то поставит ещё один разделитель перед ним. А если его нет, то поставит разделитель перед количеством и названием машины.